# PetaPoco generator error

Tags: .net, petapoco

I installed PetaPoco nuget for my web application (.NET Framework 4.5.2). I added connection string in Web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="con" connectionString="Data Source=&quot;192.168.251.232, 1444&quot;;Initial Catalog=test;User ID=test;Password=15test15"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And next I in Database.tt set connection string name

```
// Settings
ConnectionStringName = "con";           // Uses last connection string in config if not specified
Namespace = "";
RepoName = "";
GenerateOperations = true;
GeneratePocos = true;
GenerateCommon = true;
ClassPrefix = "";
ClassSuffix = "";
TrackModifiedColumns = false;
ExplicitColumns = true;
ExcludePrefix = new string[] {}; // Exclude tables by prefix.
```

I get next errors:
[image]

I tried set

```
Namespace = ConnectionStringName
```

But it doesn't work.

I have no ideas and have not found helpful informations.

Comment: I have the same issue. tried to remove all ref to PetaPoco, then re-add from nuget... no luck.

Answer (score 1):

On msdn I found and tried to fix up references as suggested here (Compiling transformation error in grid) [link here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb126247.aspx). There was some missing dlls.

But the template still was giving me these errors.

Then I found cases on internet where there is **spaces into the template** files. This alone is enough to **break the template**, **giving those sort of errors** (this [link](https://siderite.blogspot.com/2010/06/t4-error-compiling-transformation.html) helped me).

In my case I found a **end of file carriage return** ( inside PetaPoco.Core.ttinclude) that **I deleted**. And then worked like a charm.

this is unbelievable, so fragile but so practicle!

I hope this can help people not wasting lots of time if they ran into this situation.